# Kruskal algorithm in python

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, greedy, kruskals-algorithm

```
import heapq
from collections import defaultdict

a = list(map(int, input().split()))

nodes = a[0]
disjoint_set = [-1]*(nodes+1)
rank_set = [0]*(nodes+1)
edges = a[1]
heap = []

def get_parent(u):
    if disjoint_set[u] == -1:
        return u
    return get_parent(disjoint_set[u])

def make_union(x, y):
    x_parent = get_parent(x)
    y_parent = get_parent(y)
    if rank_set[x_parent] == rank_set[y_parent]:
        disjoint_set[x_parent] = y_parent
        rank_set[x_parent] +=1
    elif rank_set[x_parent] > rank_set[y_parent]:
        disjoint_set[x_parent] = y_parent
    else:
        disjoint_set[y_parent] = x_parent
def not_cycle(*item):
    x_parent = get_parent(item[1])
    y_parent = get_parent(item[2])
    if x_parent == y_parent:
        return False;
    make_union(x_parent, y_parent)
    return True

while(edges!=0):
    edge = list(map(int, input().split()))
    heapq.heappush(heap, [edge[2], edge[0], edge[1]])
    edges-=1
cnt = 0
total = 0

while(cnt!=nodes-1):
    item = heapq.heappop(heap)
    if(not_cycle(*item) is True):
        total+= item[0]
        cnt+=1
print(total)
```

I implemented the kruskal algorthm in python. I am getting RecursionError:maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison error. make_union and get_parent are method of disjoint set algorithm. I am getting the error in get_parent method. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In `not_cycle` you are passing the parents to `make_union` but then in `make_union` you are trying to get the parents again.  After the first change the parents will no longer be `-1` and you will recurse "forever"[1]

[1] *"forever" in this case is until the maximum depth of your stack.*

Answer (score -1):

```
 -

   aa,bb=list(map(int,input().split())) 
   c=[] for i in range(bb):
   z=list(map(int,input().split()))
   c.append(z) c.sort(key=lambda x: x[2])    
   a=[]
   b=[] 
   for i in c:
       a.append((i[0]-1,i[1]-1))
       b.append(i[2]) 
   arr=[] 
   size=[] 
   for i in range(len(b)):
       arr.append(i)
       size.append(1)   
   def root(i):
       while arr[i]!=i:
           i=arr[i]
           return i      

  def unions(arr,size,p,q):
       root_a=root(p)
       root_b=root(q)
       if size[root_a]>size[root_b]:
           arr[root_b]=arr[root_a]
           size[root_a]+=size[root_b]
       else:
           arr[root_a]=arr[root_b]
           size[root_b]+=size[root_a]     
  def kruskals(b,a,aa):   
       te=[]
       i=0
       while (len(te))<aa-1:
           (p,q)=a[i]
           if root(p)!=root(q):
                   te.append(b[i])
                   unions(arr,size,p,q)
           i+=1        
       return sum(te)

   print(kruskals(b,a,aa))
```

Comment: I will specially recommend you to read the tutorial of union-find from HackerEarth. thereafter you will be able to understand the code in a very easy manner......

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It would also be really helpful for the original poster if you can add more details to the code, like comments or point out where the original poster went wrong in the piece of code that you wrote.

Comment: Please add some more details like comments, suggestions, thinking process, etc.